# SQL Select Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, permissions

I have a database that I need to connect to and select from. I have an SQL Login, let's call it myusername. When I use the following, no SELECT permission shows up:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions ('dbo.mytable', 'OBJECT')
GO
```

Several times I tried things like:

```
USE mydatabase
GO

GRANT SELECT TO myusername
GO

GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::mydatabase TO myusername
GO

GRANT SELECT ON mytable TO myusername
GO
```

It says the queries execute successfully, but there is never any difference in the first query. What simple thing am I missing to grant database level select permissions.

As a note, I made double sure it was the correct user, correct database, and I have already tried granting table level select permissions. So far I keep getting the error:

```
SELECT permission denied on object 'mytable', database 'mydatabase', schema 'dbo'.
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT/UPDATE:

Upon right clicking the SQL User in SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I discovered every single Database role is checked, including db_denydatareader and db_datareader... might this be blocking my ability to grant permission at the database level? If this is so, what is the purpose of db_denydatareader? It seems silly to me to have a 'DENY' that can't be viewed when querying permissions.

SUMMARY:
Sure enough, that fixed it.

Comment: You should post your EDIT/UPDate as the accepted answer =)

Comment: You need your dba to fix your permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS - under Databases-->mydatabase-->Security-->Users-->myusername, right click the username, select properties. Under database role membership, make sure db_denydatareader is not checked as this will override whatever permissions you had granted.

Knew it was something simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reconnecting with that SQL user account?